# Find and Replace powershell

Tags: powershell

I can't figure out what i'm doing wrong. i want it to read the web.config file find (< serverName >, ServerName, or localhost) and replace with the computername and then save the file again. I also want to Change whatever the Driver letter is to the current Drive that the Script is sitting on. I know my Code is messy but i have no script writing skill at all. so if you have any suggestions on cleaning it up, that would help.

```
$env:CD = (get-location).drive.root;
$env:CL = get-location

Get-Content ($env:cl\wwwroot\GBMain\Web.config) | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace "<serverName>", "$env:COMPUTERNAME" } | Set-Content ($env:cl\wwwroot\GBMain\Web.config)
Get-Content ($env:cl\wwwroot\GBMain\Web.config) | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace "ServerName", "$env:COMPUTERNAME" } | Set-Content ($env:cl\wwwroot\GBMain\Web.config)
Get-Content ($env:cl\wwwroot\GBMain\Web.config) | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace "localhost", "$env:COMPUTERNAME" } | Set-Content ($env:cl\wwwroot\GBMain\Web.config)
Get-Content ($env:cl\wwwroot\GBMain\Web.config) | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace "D:\", "$env:cd" } | Set-Content ($env:cl\wwwroot\GBMain\Web.config)
Get-Content ($env:cl\wwwroot\GBMain\Web.config) | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace "C:\", "$env:cd" } | Set-Content ($env:cl\wwwroot\GBMain\Web.config)

Get-Content ($env:cl\wwwroot\GBReporting\Web.config) | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace "<serverName>", "$env:COMPUTERNAME" } | Set-Content ($env:cl\wwwroot\GBReporting\Web.config)
Get-Content ($env:cl\wwwroot\GBReporting\Web.config) | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace "ServerName", "$env:COMPUTERNAME" } | Set-Content ($env:cl\wwwroot\GBReporting\Web.config)
Get-Content ($env:cl\wwwroot\GBReporting\Web.config) | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace "localhost", "$env:COMPUTERNAME" } | Set-Content ($env:cl\wwwroot\GBReporting\Web.config)
Get-Content ($env:cl\wwwroot\GBReporting\Web.config) | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace "D:\", "$env:cd" } | Set-Content ($env:cl\wwwroot\GBReporting\Web.config)
Get-Content ($env:cl\wwwroot\GBReporting\Web.config) | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace "C:\", "$env:cd" } | Set-Content ($env:cl\wwwroot\GBReporting\Web.config)

Exit
```

Comment: A good start would be telling us what's not working. What errors are you receiving?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you didn't specify what was wrong, I just took a quick look over all of it. This is untested, but I believe it should work.

First, you're doing multiple reads and writes when you could combine all `replace`-commands. Paths used in `Get-Content` and `Set-Content` should be strings, so quote them. As long as the files are small, you should store the content in a variable before editing and saving it. This is an easy way to avoid trying to write to a file that's still in use(you're reading it). Finally, `-replace` uses regex, so you need to escape the `\` in `C:\` and `D:\`.

```
$env:CD = (get-location).drive.root;
$env:CL = get-location

$cont = Get-Content "$env:cl\wwwroot\GBMain\Web.config" 
$cont | ForEach-Object { 
    $_ -replace "<serverName>", "$env:COMPUTERNAME" -replace "ServerName", "$env:COMPUTERNAME" -replace "localhost", "$env:COMPUTERNAME" -replace "C:\\", "$env:cd" -replace "D:\\", "$env:cd" } |
Set-Content "$env:cl\wwwroot\GBMain\Web.config"

$cont = Get-Content "$env:cl\wwwroot\GBReporting\Web.config"
$cont | ForEach-Object { 
    $_ -replace "<serverName>", "$env:COMPUTERNAME" -replace "ServerName", "$env:COMPUTERNAME" -replace "localhost", "$env:COMPUTERNAME" -replace "C:\\", "$env:cd" -replace "D:\\", "$env:cd" } |
Set-Content "$env:cl\wwwroot\GBReporting\Web.config"


#Exit is unnecessary. A PowerShell script exists when it's done.
```